# Actionscript 2 how to read text as html instead of normal text?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am using html in xml for some names in actionscript and there is `;quot;`

Here is my variable where I want actionscript to read the name as html. Instead of normal text.

```
    var field:TextField = currItem.createH3Black(0, 0, 180, 10, h3Size, h3Leading, font, "Left", _root.white, currItem.name.toUpperCase(), "textItem");
```

How do I make actionscript treadt the `currItem.name.toUpperCase()` as html? So that the name shows as HTM with `""` . Instead of showing `;quot;`

Update here is the full source code: http://pastie.org/2666913

Comment: Do you mean that you want to replace `;quot;` with `"`?

Comment: Yes I want to do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
your_string = your_string.split(";quot;").join('"');
```